# code working only till 100th row

Tags: vba, excel

[image: not working after 100th row]
The below code is working only till 100th row.Later on not its not working.Can you please tell me why ?

```
    Sub sum1()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Double, y As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sumbalance As Integer
    Dim Reached As Boolean
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    sumbalance = 0

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For x = 2 To lastrow

    If Range("A" & x).Value = Range("A" & x + 1) Then

            sumbalance = sumbalance + Range("B" & x).Value

      End If
    Else
         sumbalance = sumbalance + Range("B" & x).Value
         Range("C" & x).Value = sumbalance
         sumbalance = 0
    End If

    Next x
    [Not summing after 100th row][1]End Sub
```

In the image,you can see its not summing after 100th row

Comment: Try `Dim x As Long, y As Long` and `Dim sumbalance As Double`.

Comment: You've got an extra `End If` before the `Else`.

Comment: Thank you .I got it working !!1

Comment: what is the conditional statement  to check if a value is present in a cell in excel?

Comment: there are a few ... maybe isempty.

Answer (score 0):

you may use formulas

for instance, your column A numbers appear to be "adjacent" (i.e. all same number occurrences are adjacent to each other) and with no possible repetitions (i.e. once some number occurrences end, it no longer appears in sequent rows). hence you could use this:

```
Sub sum1()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1<>R[1]C1,SUMIF(C1,RC1,C2),"""")"
    End With
End Sub
```

and should you want to get rid of formulas and keep their resulting values only:

```
Sub sum1()    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(, 2)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1<>R[1]C1,SUMIF(C1,RC1,C2),"""")"
            .Value = .Value
            If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```